# not assigning the value to list from another function

Tags: python-3.x

I've written some code to make very basic tic tac toe game but in my code i am trying to assign a string value as a variable (`marker`) to the list returning function called `display_board` that returns a list called `board`.

**The Problem:**

In this code the `display_board()[col_guess][row_guess] == marker` line is doing nothing here, because it's not assigning the of `marker` input variable to the that list called `board`

**The Code:**

```
from random import randint
#Step 1: Write a function that can print out a board. Set up your board as a list,
#where each index 1-9 corresponds with a number on a number pad, so you get a 3 by 3 board representation.
def display_board():
    board = []
    for play in range(0,3):
        board.append(["O"]*3)
    for joinBoard in board:
        print(" ".join(joinBoard))
        return(board)


#Step 2: Write a function that can take in a player input and assign their marker as 'X' or 'O'.
#Think about using while loops to continually ask until you get a correct answer.

def player_input():
    print("Type the board in which you want play? 'X' or 'O'")
    marker = str(input(" 'X' or 'O' ")).upper()
    print("You chose {} as a board, now we'll assign it.".format(marker))
    col_random = randint(0,3)
    print(col_random)
    row_random = randint(0,3)
    print(row_random)
    print("\n Now we'll ask you to guess the position of hidden ")
    col_guess= int(input('Guess the colum: >> '))
    row_guess = int(input('Guess the row: >> '))
    while col_guess == col_random and row_guess == row_random:
        display_board()[col_guess][row_guess] == marker
        print(display_board())
        break


player_input()
```

Comment: You have double equal sign. Change `display_board()[col_guess][row_guess] == marker` to `display_board()[col_guess][row_guess] = marker`

Comment: i tried but noting happened, the value of 'marker' is not assigning. to that list called 'board'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually

```
while col_guess == col_random and row_guess == row_random:
    display_board()[col_guess][row_guess] == marker
    print(display_board())
    break
```

This code

```
display_board()[col_guess][row_guess] == marker
```

calls the function `display_board()` and assigns what you want, BUT

You are looking at output of

```
print(display_board())
```

Which is actually again creating new list, so previous list gets destroyed. Do this.

```
while col_guess == col_random and row_guess == row_random:
    _borads = display_board()
    _borads [col_guess][row_guess] = marker
    print(_borads )
    break
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, but why the previews list destroyed could you please explain, if possible for new learner coder.

Comment: @RJT Look at the code of `display_board()`, you have `board = []` which makes a new list each time function is called, also please mark my question accepted if that helped

Comment: one last question what if i define `display_board` with one argument like this `display_board(board)` and i call it like this `display_board([])` here is called board argument with empty list how it would affect current code?

Comment: You are saying you will pass empty list while calling that function, it will behave exactly same as it is doing now, means, a new list is being created each time function is called